# Reportlab how to get a flowable's coordinates on BaseDocTemplate?

Tags: python, reportlab

I want to get the starting or ending x and y positions of the flowable on a page.
I've looked through the **repr**() and source code, but it isn't obvious to me how to get these. I am aware that you're not "*supposed*" to know these coordinates, but for my use case it would be quite handy. Any help would be much appreciated!